# How to navigate from a presentational component using react-router?

Tags: react-router

I'm working on a personal project, it's a simple blog app using ReactJS. I have 1 screen for the **entry list page**, and 1 for the **entry details page**.

Now, I'm trying to follow the best practices, so I laid out my components as this:

- **Entry List Container**: container component. Handles fetching entries retrieval and updating application state by dispatching redux actions.
- **Entry List**: presentational component. Receives an `Array` of `Entry` objects and shows a list of them
- **Entry Details Container**: container component. Handles more application state update logic, fetching, etc.  Receives an `Entry` object
- **Entry Details**: presentational component. Displays the entry.

Basically both containers renders their presentational counterpart.

Now, the problem is the navigation. In my `App` component I'm rendering a couple of `Route` components, one is rendering the `EntryListContainer`, and another one should render the `EntryDetailContainer`.

Problem is, how do I navigate from `EntryList` ?

My hierarchy is something like this:

- EntryListContainer

  - EntryList

    - EntryRow  -----> This contains a button to navigate.
- EntryDetailsContainer

  - EntryPage

I suppose I could render a `Link` inside `EntryRow`, something like

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/{entry.id}`} />
```

But then I'd have to pass down the `match` object down from `EntryListContainer` to `EntryList` to `EntryRow, and it feels smelly.

How do I navigate properly?